# python::boost modules over aliases : RecursionError

Tags: c++, python-3.x, boost-python

So I am working with python boost. The goal for me is to be able to overload c++ functions from python modules. I have managed that, but I have observed a weird behavior when using aliases.

I have recreated a basic examples to reproduce the error :

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// CppBase class
class CppBase {
 public:
  CppBase(){};  // Default constructor

  virtual std::string myOverridableCallback() {
    return "Callback triggered from CppBase";  // Default implementation
  }

  virtual void display() {
    std::cout << "CppBase class display function" << std::endl;
    std::cout << this->myOverridableCallback() << std::endl;
  }
};

// CppBase class WRAPPER
struct CppBaseWrap : public CppBase, boost::python::wrapper<CppBase> {
 public:
  virtual std::string myOverridableCallback() override {
    // Check if override is provided in Python
    if (boost::python::override f =
            this->get_override("myOverridableCallback")) {
      return f();  // Call the Python version
    }
    return CppBase::myOverridableCallback();  // Call the Default implementation
  }
};

// CppDerived class
class CppDerived : public CppBase {
 public:
  CppDerived() {}  // Default constructor

  void show() {
    std::cout << "CppDerived class show function" << std::endl;
    std::cout << this->myOverridableCallback() << std::endl;
  }
};

using CppDerivedCopy = CppDerived;

// CppDerived class WRAPPER
struct CppDerivedWrap : public CppDerived, boost::python::wrapper<CppDerived> {
  virtual std::string myOverridableCallback() override {
    // Check if override is provided in Python
    if (boost::python::override f =
            this->get_override("myOverridableCallback")) {
      return f();  // Call the Python version
    }
    return CppBase::myOverridableCallback();  // Call the Default implementation
  }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(InheritedFunctionTest) {
  // Expose the CppBase class
  boost::python::class_<CppBaseWrap, boost::noncopyable>("CppBase", boost::python::init<>())
      .def("myOverridableCallback", &CppBaseWrap::myOverridableCallback)
      .def("display", &CppBase::display);

  // Expose the CppDerived class
  boost::python::class_<CppDerivedWrap, boost::python::bases<CppBase>, boost::noncopyable>("CppDerived", boost::python::init<>())
      .def("myOverridableCallback", &CppDerived::myOverridableCallback)
      .def("show", &CppDerived::show);

  // Expose the CppDerivedCopy class
  boost::python::class_<CppDerivedWrap, boost::python::bases<CppBase>, boost::noncopyable>("CppDerivedCopy", boost::python::init<>())
      .def("myOverridableCallback", &CppDerivedCopy::myOverridableCallback)
      .def("show", &CppDerivedCopy::show);
}
```

So as you can see, I have `using CppDerivedCopy = CppDerived;`. The idea for me is to be able in python to `from InheritedFunctionTest import CppDerivedCopy` and have the exact same behavior as if it were `CppDerived`.

My code compiles, and this is my python basic example:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('./build')
import InheritedFunctionTest


derived_obj = InheritedFunctionTest.CppDerived()
derived_obj.show()  # Calls show from Derived and myCallback from CppBase

derived_obj2 = InheritedFunctionTest.CppDerivedCopy()
derived_obj2.show()  # Calls show from Derived and myCallback from CppBase
```

this will trigger following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_script.py", line 13, in <module>
    derived_obj.show()  # Calls show from Derived and myCallback from CppBase
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

So here the `InheritedFunctionTest.CppDerived()` triggers this error.  And here comes the weird behavior, if in my cpp code I had exposed `CppDerivedCopy` before `CppDerived` (so simply reversing the last 2 blocs of code in the c++ file), I'd have the same error but on the `InheritedFunctionTest.CppDerivedCopy()` object, and the `InheritedFunctionTest.CppDerived()` object did not cause any issue.

So the last of the 2 declarations will have no issues, and the first will have this RecursionError.

I have tried a lot of different things but I don't get the root of the issue, chatGPT doesn't either, and google did not give me much documentation. Any help would be greatly appreciated !!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please test the modified Boost.Python code provided below to see if it resolves the recursion error. Make sure to replace your existing code with the following changes:

1. Use `call` instead of `get_override` in the `myOverridableCallback` function.

```cpp
virtual std::string myOverridableCallback() override {
  namespace bp = boost::python;
  bp::object pyOverride = this->get_override("myOverridableCallback");
  if (pyOverride) {
    return bp::extract<std::string>(pyOverride());
  }
  return CppBase::myOverridableCallback();
}
// Expose the CppBase class
boost::python::class_<CppBaseWrap, boost::noncopyable>("CppBase", boost::python::init<>())
    .def("display", &CppBase::display);

// Expose the CppDerived class
boost::python::class_<CppDerivedWrap, boost::python::bases<CppBase>, boost::noncopyable>("CppDerived", boost::python::init<>())
    .def("myOverridableCallback", &CppDerived::myOverridableCallback)
    .def("show", &CppDerived::show);
// Expose the CppBase class
boost::python::class_<CppBaseWrap, boost::noncopyable>("CppBase", boost::python::init<>())
    .def("display", &CppBase::display)
    .def("myOverridableCallback", &CppBase::myOverridableCallback);

// Expose the CppDerived class
boost::python::class_<CppDerivedWrap, boost::python::bases<CppBase>, boost::noncopyable>("CppDerived", boost::python::init<>())
    .def("show", &CppDerived::show);
```

Comment: don't see any 'call' in your code, and it seems you are exposing twice the CppBase class, and no CppDerivedCopy. That intended ?

Comment: One potential reason for this is that you're using the same setup for both CppDerived and CppDerivedCopy. Imagine it like having two very similar things, and sometimes they confuse the system.

To fix this, you can think of them as two different things and set them up differently. In your code, you'd create separate ways to handle CppDerived and CppDerivedCopy so that the system doesn't get confused between the two.